# Screenshots not getting added to Extent reports 4 when multiple test status is being sent to reports

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports

I have set the Parent test for @Test and child node for @Methods, when I'm sending multiple test status (pass or fail) to reports the screenshots are not being added when the test fails, but the screenshot is added when only when one status is sent for that @method.

[This method has multiple statuses sent but screenshots are not added. Image is present in local but not appended to report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl6vh.png)

[This method has only one status sent so the screenshot is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPU68.png)

Here I'm setting the test and node to @Test and @method

```
package modules;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class openBrowser implements auto_constant {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String extBrowser;
    public static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> parentTest = new ThreadLocal<ExtentTest>();
    public static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> test = new ThreadLocal<ExtentTest>();
//  static String screenShotPath = screenPath + "/screenshot " + dateFunc.getShotDate();

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setupExtent() {
        extentReports.attRepo();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setChildTests() {
        ExtentTest child = parentTest.get().createNode(extBrowser);
        test.set(child);
    }

    @BeforeTest(description = "Checking the browser and launching it")
    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    public void beforeTest(String browser) {

        /*
         * Setting every @Test as parent node
         * Name will be the class name of that @Test
         */
        ExtentTest parent = extentReports.extent.createTest(getClass().getName());
        parentTest.set(parent);

        /*
         * This assigns the browser driver to use for the extent reports for setting child node
         */
        openBrowser.extBrowser = browser;

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().arch64().setup();
            if (Property.getProperty("head").equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                setDriver(new ChromeDriver());
            } else {
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--headless");
                setDriver(new ChromeDriver(options));
            }
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().arch64().setup();
            if (Property.getProperty("head").equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                setDriver(new FirefoxDriver());
            } else {
                FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                options.addArguments("--headless");
                setDriver(new FirefoxDriver(options));
            }
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterTest(description = "Terminating the browser instance and reports")
    public void afterTest() {
        if (Property.getProperty("extent").equalsIgnoreCase("on")) {
            extentReports.extent.flush();
        }
        driver.close();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
        if (Property.getProperty("extent").equalsIgnoreCase("on")) {
            if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
                test.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
            else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
                test.get().skip(result.getThrowable());
            else
                test.get().pass("Test passed");
        }
    }

    public void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        openBrowser.driver = driver;
//      driver = drive;
    }

}
```

Here I'm sending the status to reports by calling Assertion method

```
package pageModels;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;

import modules.Assertion;
import modules.Property;
import modules.excelUtils;
import modules.extentReports;
import modules.openBrowser;

public class signup_login_Page extends openBrowser {
    ExtentTest extTest;

    /*
     * Login page Web Elements
     */
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='block-content']/form/fieldset/div[4]/div/button/span")
    private WebElement sign_Submit;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='email-error']")
    private WebElement email_error;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='pass-error']")
    private WebElement pass_error;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='panel header'] //li[@class='greet welcome']/span")
    private WebElement userName;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='email']")
    private WebElement emailBox;
    @FindBy(xpath = "(//input[@id='pass'])[1]")
    private WebElement passBox;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='messages']/div/div")
    private WebElement emptyLogErr;

    /*
     * Constructor Sets the driver to Current page
     */
    public signup_login_Page(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    /*
     * Checks if error messages are displayed when fields are empty
     */
    public void checkError() throws Exception {
        extTest = extentReports.extentTest();
sign_Submit.click();
        modules.wait.waitVisible(email_error);

        // Comparing Error Messages
        Assertion.assertEquals(email_error.getText(), excelUtils.getData(Property.getProperty("sheetName"), 2, 6),
                extTest, "Proper error msg for 'Email Field' is displayed",
                "Proper error msg for 'Email Field' is NOT displayed");
        Assertion.assertEquals(pass_error.getText(), excelUtils.getData(Property.getProperty("sheetName"), 2, 6),
                extTest, "Proper error msg for 'Password Field' is displayed",
                "Proper error msg for 'Password Field' is NOT displayed");

    }

    /*
     * Login with valid credentials Checks the header for username to verify
     * Successful login
     */
    public void signin() throws Exception {
        extTest = extentReports.extentTest();

        int cell = 4;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//form[@class='form form-login']/fieldset/div/div)[" + i + "]/input"))
                    .sendKeys(excelUtils.getData("userData", 2, cell++));
        }
//      actions.moveClick(sign_Submit);
        sign_Submit.click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
//      modules.wait.fluentVisible(userName);
        String fullName = excelUtils.getData(Property.getProperty("sheetName"), 2, 2) + " "
                + excelUtils.getData(Property.getProperty("sheetName"), 2, 3);
        String[] acName = userName.getText().split(",");
        Assertion.assertContains(acName[1].trim().substring(0, acName[0].trim().length() - 1), fullName, extTest,
                "Logged in Successfully", "User could NOT login");
    }

}
```

Here I'm sending the status to extent reports after assertion along with screenshot

```
package modules;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.IReporter;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.MediaEntityBuilder;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;

public class Assertion implements IReporter {

    /*
     * Asserting the two Strings The result is recorded in Report if reports are
     * enabled
     */
    public static void assertEquals(String actual, String expected, ExtentTest extTest, String passMsg,
            String failMsg) {
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
            if (extentReports.xclude(extTest)) {
                extTest.log(Status.PASS, passMsg);
            }
            System.out.println(passMsg);

            /*
             * Handling Assertion Error
             */
        } catch (AssertionError error) {
            if (extentReports.xclude(extTest)) {
                /*
                 * Adding the Screen capture to the ExtentReports and handling it if file not
                 * found
                 */
                try {
                    extTest.fail(failMsg,
                            MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshot.shot(failMsg)).build());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Could NOT find the Screenshot");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(failMsg);
        }
    }
```

Using this below method for creating the child node for every method

```
/*
     * Creates a new Extent test and returns the extentTest object
     */
    public static ExtentTest extentTest() {

        if(Property.getProperty("extent").equalsIgnoreCase("on")) {
            StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
            ExtentTest child = parentTest.get().createNode(stackTrace[2].getMethodName());
            return child;
        }else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

It would help a lot if this issue is solved. I'm not getting any error too to debug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assertion.assertEquals(email_error.getText(), excelUtils.getData(Property.getProperty("sheetName"), 2, 6),
                extTest, "Proper error msg for 'Email Field' is displayed",
                "Proper error msg for 'Email Field' is NOT displayed");
        Assertion.assertEquals(pass_error.getText(), excelUtils.getData(Property.getProperty("sheetName"), 2, 6),
                extTest, "Proper error msg for 'Password Field' is displayed",
                "Proper error msg for 'Password Field' is NOT displayed");
```

The image was not getting uploaded because I was sending the Fail message having text in Single Quotes after removing the Single Quotes in the Fail Message the image got uploaded.

I don't know why but it worked.

```
Assertion.assertEquals(email_error.getText(), excelUtils.getData(Property.getProperty("sheetName"), 2, 6),
                extTest, "Proper error msg for Email Field is displayed",
                "Proper error msg for Email Field is NOT displayed");
        Assertion.assertEquals(pass_error.getText(), excelUtils.getData(Property.getProperty("sheetName"), 2, 6),
                extTest, "Proper error msg for Password Field is displayed",
                "Proper error msg for Password Field is NOT displayed");
```